# What is the difference between "his participating" and "his participation"?

Tags: grammar

I don't  understand the difference between each of the following pairs.

Example 1

- A: My boss encourages his participating in conferences.
- B: My boss encourages his participation in conferences.

Example 2

- C: He is used to eat rice.
- D: He is used to eating rice.

Comment: Can you clarify your examples.  *B* is grammatically incorrect, as is *C* (unless you are anthropomorphising a spoon)...

Comment: @jimbobmcgee: "Encouraging his participation in  conferences" seems to be natural to me. I don't understand why it is incorrect grammatically, could you post an answer for this question?

Comment: Fixing the typo in *B* (encourage**s**) makes *B* read correctly.  *C* is still incorrect, though.

Answer (score 1):

B and C are both grammatically incorrect. B would would if you said

"My boss encourages his participation in conferences." - this could've been a typo on your end but just pointing it out in case. If you only say encourage it does not work.

Also example C: Saying "He is used to eat rice" sounds like someone is using a person as a slave to eat rice. It doesn't make sense. D would be the correct way to say it.

Comment: It was a typo. So what the difference between A and B?

Comment: This one is quite hard for me to explain, B sounds better to my ear and it sounds proper, however, I know that is not an answer that would help you to understand it. The way I could see "A" working out and sounding correct would be "My boss encourages him participating in conferences" However that has a different meaning to me.